# How do I tell someone I had a great time the last time I saw them

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I went to lunch with a group of friends yesterday, and one of my friends brought two new people whom I did not know.

Today I bump into one of the new ones, and I wanted to be polite and tell the person that I had a great time at lunch.

I have read several places on the internet, that saying "Thank you for yesterday" has a sexual undertone to it.

Is that true? Or how else would you say it?

Comment: 'It was great meeting you yesterday", "It was great getting to know you better",  "I was laughing at your story you told us about xyz last night',   "I'm really glad we had lunch together yesterday...it was fun." It is normal to say these types of things... not unusual at all.  (It's almost even expected in some cases)

Comment: "thanking" someone for lunch would usually be reserved for if they did you a favor,  at the lunch(gave you advice) or paid for the lunch'.  If you were thanking them for advice you'd say "thanks for the advice".  Perhaps "thank you for going out to lunch yesterday, I was so happy to get out of the lunchroom" could work I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, reading a sexual undertone into an innocuous statement like **Thank you for yesterday** seems kind of weird—unless it's said with a leer and/or wink to someone *with whom you had sex yesterday*. Other than that, **Thank you for yesterday** could mean anything, and certainly doesn't have a subtext—or even a *text-level* text—that's sexual in and of itself. Where did you read this?

To answer your question, you could say **Thank you for *lunch* yesterday** to avoid all confusion. Of course, if **lunch** is used as a euphemism for sex by someone, then you're on your own!